# Setting image in list control item

Tags: mfc

I want to set image only in particular rows of listctrl.

If I use CListCtrl's SetImageList, it is setting image in first column of each row.

Is it possible to set image only in whichever row I want.

Comment: Why don't you add a blank image to the image list and set the ones you want to have that entry?

Comment: Post some code, as maybe there's an issue with the implementation you're using, because should be possible. Additionally, is it the ROW or COLUMN you're trying to resolve for the image, as they're not the same ie pick one.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a little bit messy but it works for me.

If your CListCtrl has LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style, than you can decide which column which image will have.
For this purpose you need to set extended style LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES for your list after it will be created. Than you add CImageList
field to your CListCtrl-derived class, for example it will have m_imgList name. This field has to be initialized with default values 
and with image resource that will be using. After that you have to call SetImageList and pass it m_imgList. As long as your list will 
have LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style you need to implement DrawItem function in which you will call something like this for image drawing:

```
LVITEM lvItem   = {0};
lvItem.mask     = LVIF_IMAGE;
lvItem.iSubItem = nCol;         // column index
lvItem.iItem    = nItem;        // item index 

GetItem(&lvItem);

POINT p;    // init it like you want
pDC         // pointer on device context

m_imgList.Draw(pDC, lvItem.iImage, p, ILD_MASK);
```

And before that, when you will fill the list with values, you have to fill in LVITEM structure for needed column:

```
LVITEM lvItem   = {0};
lvItem.iItem    = nItem;    // item index
lvItem.iSubItem = i;        // column index
lvItem.iImage   = nImg;     // image index from imageList
lvItem.mask     = LVIF_IMAGE;
```

And after that you have to call InsertItem or SetItem with this lvItem parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve it is adding a transparent image in your CImageList and set it on the list item you don't want the image to appear.